# why i am getting double the frequency count of vowels?

Tags: python, list

So i was solving a question that is in my Lab practical Syllabus. Below is the question:-

> Write a python class to reverse a sentence (initialized via
> constructor) word by word. Example:  “I am here” should be reversed as
> “here am I”. Create instances of this class for each of the three
> strings input by the user and display the reversed string for each, in
> descending order of number of vowels in the string.

Below is code for the implementation of above question:-

```
class sentenceReverser:
  vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
  vowelCount =0
  sentence=""
  reversed_string = ""
  def __init__(self,sentence):
    self.sentence = sentence
    self.reverser()
  def reverser(self):
    self.reversed_string = " ".join(reversed(self.sentence.split()))
    return self.reversed_string
  def getVowelCount(self):
    for i in self.sentence:
      if i.lower() in self.vowels:
        self.vowelCount += 1
    return self.vowelCount

inp = []

for i in range(2):    
  temp = input("Enter string:- ") 
  ob = sentenceReverser(temp)
  inp.append(ob)

sorted_item = sorted(inp,key = lambda inp:inp.getVowelCount(),reverse=True)

for i in range (len(sorted_item)):
  print('Reversed String: ',sorted_item[i].reverser(),'Vowel count: ',sorted_item[i].getVowelCount())
```

Below is output i am getting for the above code:-

[image: output image]

**issue:-**
Could someone tell me why i am getting double the vowel count???

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: `getVowelCount` updates `self.vowelCount` & you are calling that twice. Once during sorting, again during printing. Resulting in double the actual count.

Comment: To add to @rdas answer. You should probably make the choice between updated a class attribute (`self.something`) and returning. If you're only using `getVowelCount` to get the count then there's no need to set `self.vowelCount`, just count the occurrences within the function and return the value. If you want a stored `self.voewCount` for something else later then have it add as you did but later instead of calling `self.getVowelCount()` again to get the value just use `sorted_item[i].vowelCount`

Comment: Also note that first you have `vowelCount` and `sentence` as class attributes, then in the methods you work with instance attributes

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `getVowelCount()` twice. Instead you can use the variable instead of calling in the print command

```
for i in range (len(sorted_item)):
  print('Reversed String: ',sorted_item[i].reverser(),'Vowel count: ',sorted_item[i].vowelCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't reset vowel count in the method. So if you execute the method once (here in sort), you'll get correct count. If you execute it twice (in printing), you will get twice as much. If you execute it once more, you'll get 3x correct amount. And so on.

The solution is to reset the number:

```py
  def getVowelCount(self):
    self.vowelCount = 0
    for i in self.sentence:
      if i.lower() in self.vowels:
        self.vowelCount += 1
    return self.vowelCount
```

Or to calculate it only once - set it to None, then calculate only `if self.vowelCount is None`, otherwise return existing value.